# Load component in a page after href redirection in ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In reactJs my href links to new page. How can I load another component on that page.

```
<Dropdown.Item href="#/action-1">New Orders</Dropdown.Item>
```

And I want to load newOrder component on #/action-1. This is the sample component newOrder.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

export class newOrder extends Component{

        render(){
            return(
                <div>
                   <h1>These are your new orders</h1> 
                </div>
            )
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does action-1 exist in your application? And if yes, You can simply handle the new component to be rendered in your routes.

Comment: yes and it links to a new page and I want to load my component there. @G_S

Answer (score 0):

Using "href" inside react application violate SPA rule as it reloads the page.

My suggestion would be to use Link component.

```
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';

<Link to='/action-1'>
    <Dropdown.Item>New Orders</Dropdown.Item>
</Link>
```

Or you can add a function to redirect to /action-1 using withRouter.

```
import {withRouter} from 'react-router-dom';

<Dropdown.Item onClick={navigateToAction}>New Orders</Dropdown.Item>
```

Comment: Can I redirect to another component? let's say NewOrder component.

Comment: You need to have a concept of react-router. 
https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start